# grep with -f like in PHP

Tags: php, grep

Is there such a function in PHP that does grep -f filename in unix/linux systems.
If there is none, what PHP functions/tools would help in creating a customised method/function for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually IMHO, I'd say it's the following:

```
$result = preg_grep($pattern, file($path));
```

See [`preg_grep`<sup>­*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_grep) and [`file`<sup>­*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/file).

If you need to do that (recursively) over a set of files, there is also [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) and `foreach` or the (`Recursive`)`DirectoryIterator` or the [`GlobIterator`<sup>­*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/GlobIterator) and not to forget the [`RegexIterator`<sup>­*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/RegexIterator).

---

Example with **SplFileObject** and **RegexIterator**:

```
$stream = new SplFileObject($file); 
$grepped = new RegexIterator($stream, $pattern); 

foreach ($grepped as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Output (all lines of `$file` containing $pattern):

```
$grepped = new RegexIterator($stream, $pattern); 
foreach ($grepped as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/208699

Comment: While this is functionally equivalent, it does load the entire file into memory, while command line grep does not.

Comment: @cmd: Yes, if you want to save memory, please consider [**SplFileObject**](http://php.net/SplFileObject) and [**RegexIterator**](http://php.net/RegexIterator).

Comment: sounds good! ... you wouldn't happen to have an example at hand that is a drop-in replacement for preg_grep($pattern, file($path)) ?

Comment: @cmc: See the addition I put to the answer, it shows such an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the [file_get_contens()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function to open a file and the [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function to capture contents using a regex.

```
$file = file_get_contents ('path/to/file.ext');
preg_match_all ('regex_pattern_here', $file, $matches);
print_r ($matches);
```

Comment: I have been using `file_get_contents()` but it fails intermittently.