# how to judge the difference between the 2 files

Tags: php

there are two php files with same name here

```
a/hello.php,
b/hello.php
```

if a/hello.php is defferent with b/hello.php (for some reason I update the a/hello.php , then I need to sync the b/hello.php the same with a/hello.php) ,copy a/hello.php to b/hello.php
but how to know that a/hello.php is diffrent with b/hello.php? filemtime() seems not the same even they are really the same.

Comment: If the file is not too large, you could consider computing a hash like `md5` on the contents and comparing them.

Comment: `filemtime` is for getting the time when a file was last modified, not by its content

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663641/grep-with-f-like-in-php

Comment: look here <http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unix program `cmp` is optimised for this sort of thing.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmp_(Unix)

I understand it reads the files until the first difference is found. That way it doesn't have to read the whole file.

If you program has access to a Unix terminal I think this would be the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you use notepad++ editor then you can use compare plugin for the compare two files...
each editor have a this functionality you can use it

Comment: i assume the OP was asking of a programmatic solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can load both of the files into arrays with file(), and then use array-diff() on them:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php