# Recursively search all directories for an array of strings in php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, file-search

I am new to PHP coding and here am looking for fastest way to do recursive search on all directories for an array of strings.

I am doing this way

```
$contents_list = array("xyz","abc","hello"); // this list can grow any size
$path = "/tmp/"; //user will give any path which can contain multi level sub directories

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $filename => $file) {
    $fd = fopen($file,'r');
    if($fd) {
        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $line = fgets($fd);
            foreach($contents_list as $content) {
                if(strpos($line, $content) != false) {
                    echo $line."\n";
                }
            }         
        }
    }
    fclose($fd);
}
```

Here I am recursively iterating over all directories and then again on each file iterate over contents array to search.

Is there any better way to do kind of search ? Please suggest for faster alternative.

Thanks

Comment: There was a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663641/grep-with-f-like-in-php Might this help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're allowed to execute shell commands in your environment (and assuming you're running your script on *nix), you could call the native grep command recursively. That would give you the fastest results.

```
$contents_list = array("xyz","abc","hello");
$path = "/tmp/";
$pattern = implode('\|', $contents_list) ;
$command = "grep -r '$pattern' $path";
$output = array();
exec($command, $output);
foreach ($output as $match) {
    echo $match . '\n';
}
```

If the `disable_functions` directive is in effect and you can't call grep, you could use your approach with `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and reading the files line by line, using strpos on each line. Please note that `strpos` requires a strict equality check (use `!== false` instead of `!= false`), otherwise you'll skip matches at the beginning of a line.

A slightly faster way is to use glob recusively to obtain a list of files, and read those files at once instead of scanning them line by line. According to my tests, this approach will give you about 30-35% time advantage over yours.

```
function recursiveDirList($dir, $prefix = '') {
    $dir = rtrim($dir, '/');
    $result = array();

    foreach (glob("$dir/*", GLOB_MARK) as &$f) {
        if (substr($f, -1) === '/') {
            $result = array_merge($result, recursiveDirList($f, $prefix . basename($f) . '/'));
        } else {
            $result[] = $prefix . basename($f);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$files = recursiveDirList($path);
foreach ($files as $filename) {

    $file_content = file($path . '/' . $filename);
    foreach ($file_content as $line) {
        foreach($contents_list as $content) {
            if(strpos($line, $content) !== false) {
                echo $line . '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Credit for the recursive glob function goes to http://proger.i-forge.net/3_ways_to_recursively_list_all_files_in_a_directory/Opc

To sum it up, performance-wise you have the following rankings (results in seconds for a farly large directory containing ~1200 files recusively, using two common text patterns):

1. call grep via exec() - 2.2015s
2. use recursive `glob` and read files with `file()` - 9.4443s
3. use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and read files with `readline()` - 15.1183s

Answer (score 0):

Even 2013 there was a - in my eyes much more readable - PHP native way to iterate recursively over a directory tree: the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) class.

Have a look at this sample:

```
<?php

  // Initialize Recursive Iterator

  $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( 'path/to/project/' );
  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $directory );
  $regex = new RegexIterator( $iterator, '/^.+\.php$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH );

  // Iterate over files

  $files = array();
  foreach ( $regex as $info ) {
    // Do something with file to be found at $info->getPathname()
  }

?>
```

Best regards from Salzburg!